# CSS parsing: matching specific entities using cssparser

Tags: java, css, css-parsing

For [one of my projects](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator), which validates JSON using JSON Schema, I miss accurate code for two `format` specifications: `color` and `style`.

The first specification, `color`, denotes whatever color is valid in CSS 2.1. The second, `style`, is whatever CSS 2.1 considers as a style.

I have two problems:

- I don't know CSS that much;
- I have the devil's time using [cssparser](http://cssparser.sourceforge.net) to do the job.

The current code ([here](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eel/kitchen/jsonschema/keyword/common/format/CSSColorValidator.java) for `color` and [here](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eel/kitchen/jsonschema/keyword/common/format/CSSStyleValidator.java) for `style`) will definitely allow invalid inputs, and disallow potentially valid inputs... Also, I wish I could use jStyleParser (part of the cssbox project), unfortunately it is not available on Maven, which is a requirement for me.

How can you use `cssparser` to accurately identify both format specifications above, if at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, there is no such color as "fuschia" (CSSColorValidator.java:42), so your bets are off. It should read "fuchsia" instead. Also, "#[\da-f]{1,6}" is not a good way to parse hash-colors, they can have ONLY 3 or 6 hex digits. Either contribute to the cssparser project or find a better parser :(